# My reputation is smaller than it should be

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation was 1172 this morning. I added my Yahoo account open ID to my profile, and now my reputation is only 1132, without receiving any downvotes or something which could affect negatively my reputation. What is the problem?

Comment: I suspect that adding login credentials triggered a rep-recalc. Check out [http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) while you're logged in. There you can find a detailed summary of your reputation as computed by the system. The differences may appear for instance when you deleted an answer with some upvotes. More details can be found in the links in the second part of the answer in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-did-i-lose-rep/1716#1716), for example.

Comment: Ok. I know precisely that my reputation was 1172 this morning because I got upvoted last night a few times on a question, and those votes do not appear in today's reputation count. This means I got at least 2 upvotes today, and the reputation counter says that I have +10 rep today. Anyway, maybe it's just a count error, and it will correct itself.

Comment: It's possible that some time over the past few days, a user who had upvoted you 4 times (for +40) had their account deleted, which removes their votes.  The removal of those votes, though, is not accounted for immediately, only on the next rep recalc.

Comment: May be someone, removed their votes against your answer, and  removed 2 of your accepted answers. Which means, you loose $-15 -15 -10=-40$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, users can undo accepted answers at any time, or upvotes within a 5 minute vote grace period. Also, if the post has been *edited* since the last time they voted, they can also undo the vote at will.

Check the reputation tab on your user page, and https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation for details, but remember that reverted votes will not be shown anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

May be someone, removed their votes against your answer, and  removed 2 of your accepted answers. Which means, you lose 40 since $-15 -15 -10=-40$

Comment: why a downvote? Anything wrong with this

Comment: Ok. That is possible, although I verified my questions and answers, and they're all like there were before. I know that a notification appears when an answer is accepted. Shouldn't that happen if the answer is not accepted anymore? And for Chandru, I think that even if someone upvotes me and then takes back the vote, the change in reputation is +10-1, not +10-10.

Comment: @Beni: No, you didn't get my point. For example, if I upvote you for answer you get $+10$, but after two minutes, I can take back my vote and you loose $+10$. That is before the vote gets **locked** I can take it back.

Comment: @Beni: If a vote is withdrawn, it is indeed as if it never happened, so +10-10 for a retracted upvote, -2+2 for a retracted downvote. And no, unfortunately there's no notification for an unaccepted answer.

Comment: I guess he either lost $+40$ or gained $-40$. ;)